# CloudFirestore Triggers :How to get the data of the triggered firestore document in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a cloud functions to get the triggered document data . But I am getting [object object]

My code is :

```
exports.accept = functions.firestore
.document('deyaPayUsers/{aID}/Split/{aID1}/ReceivedInvitation/{autoIds}')
  .onWrite(event=>{
  const db1 = admin.firestore();
  const MAuth = event.params.aID;
  console.log("mauthid"+MAuth);
  const MAuth1 = event.params.aID1;
  const resautoid = event.params.autoIds;
  console.log("resss"+resautoid);
var document = event.data.data();//not getting data 
    console.log("newvalue is :"+document);it prints [object object]

  });
```

How to get the data using cloud functions from FireStore triggers.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `event.data.data()` you get the document data back as a JavaScript object. Apparently that `[Object object]` is how a JavaScript object is printed. If you want to see the JSON as a string, use `JSON.stringify` to convert it. E.g.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(event.data.data());
```

To make it easier to read the JSON, you might also want to consider:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(event.data.data(), null, '  ');
```

For more information see the [documentation for `JSON.stringify` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(event.data.data(), null, '  ');
at these line I am getting the data of the document. But I need to get the specific field when I try to do   var document = JSON.stringify(event.data.data(), null, '  ');
                    console.log("document is doc"+document);// here I am getting the document data 
                    var senderauthid = document.SenderID;// undefined is getting