# firestore : why retrieved data is not getting into an variable in cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I retrieved the data from firestore. when that retrieved data is storing into a variable I am getting [object object].I didn't understand why it happens?

My code is

```
 var dbref = db1.collection('deyaPayUsers').doc(sendauthid).collection('Split').doc(sendauthid).collection('SentInvitations').doc(senderautoid);
         var fulldoc = dbref.get()
                            .then(doc => {
                            if(!doc.exists){
                            console.log('No such document');
                            }else{
                            console.log('Document data :',doc.data());
                                d1 = doc.data();// here I am not getting the data
                                console.log("d1 is"+d1);
}
});
```

Comment: Are you using fire store or firebase?

Comment: I am using firestore

Comment: You'll need to call `JSON.stringify` to convert the JavaScript object to a readable JSON representation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380968/cloudfirestore-triggers-how-to-get-the-data-of-the-triggered-firestore-document/49385737#49385737

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CloudFirestore Triggers :How to get the data of the triggered firestore document in cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380968/cloudfirestore-triggers-how-to-get-the-data-of-the-triggered-firestore-document)

Comment: If I use JSON.stringify How can I retrieve a specific field from that

Answer (score 0):

I dint know what you what you actually want to achieve, because you have shared incomplete code. However I hope code below will help you.

```
const db = firebase.firestore()
let self = this;
 db.collection("User")
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
            querySnapshot.forEach((result) => {
              let data = result.data();
              data.id = result.id;
             console.log(data)
            })
          } else {
            console.log("no data found")
          }
        }
        );
```

Comment: I am using cloud functions